# Android fails load driver touchscreen on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: android, linux-device-driver

Can you help me with this:
My tablet Galaxy Tab 10.1, after reset pressing power button 15 seconds making a soft reset because freeze loading an app, not load touchscreen driver.
Dmesg message:

```
<6>[    7.163493] mXT1386: mxt_probe
<6>[    7.163501] maXTouch driver
<6>[    7.163507]    "sec_touch"
<6>[    7.163513]   addr:   0x004c
<6>[    7.163519]   irq:    220
<6>[    7.163525]   flags:  0x0000
<6>[    7.163531]   adapter:"Tegra I2C adapter"
<6>[    7.163537]   device: "(null)"
<3>[    7.163685] tegra-i2c tegra-i2c.1: I2c error status 0x00000008
<3>[    7.169602] tegra-i2c tegra-i2c.1: no acknowledge from address 0x4c
<3>[    7.176023] tegra-i2c tegra-i2c.1: Packet status 0x00010009
<6>[    7.182700] Warning: To wake up touch-ic in deep sleep, retry i2c communication!
<3>[    7.222752] tegra-i2c tegra-i2c.1: I2c error status 0x00000008
<3>[    7.228727] tegra-i2c tegra-i2c.1: no acknowledge from address 0x4c
<3>[    7.235061] tegra-i2c tegra-i2c.1: Packet status 0x00010009
<3>[    7.241798] sec_touch 1-004c: Failure accessing maXTouch device
<3>[    7.247800] sec_touch 1-004c: Chip could not be identified
<6>[    7.253434] p3_touch_exit_hw
<4>[    7.253455] sec_touch: probe of 1-004c failed with error 255
<6>[    7.253510] Successfully added driver sec_touch
```

How can I sure of if is a hardware issue or a configuration issue?

I clean cache, data, system folders from CWM and reinstall stock rom p7510uekmm and nothing happend

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with my Galaxy Tab and tried the ideas mentioned above but it just didn't work for me. I have, however, figured out what's really going wrong.

I always had this failure showing up in dmesg:

tegra-i2c tegra-i2c.1: no acknowledge from address 0x4c

So, it can't read from the touchscreen controller at address 0x4c because the chip isn't responding. One fix mentioned was to re-write the configuration, with the assumption that the device was somehow wedged. That doesn't work either, since you can't write to 0x4c - same lack of acknowledgement. So, if 0x4c is the right address, the chip must be dead, right?

I tried adding a reset. No change. Disconnected the battery overnight. Also no change.

Then, I realized what's going on. The MXT1386 has a "Firmware Update" mode. When you put it into update mode, the device address changes from 0x4c to 0x26! Once it gets into that mode, it doesn't respond to the original address. Since I don't have the docs for the device, and thus don't know how to get out of firmware update mode, I updated the Linux kernel to call the driver function that updates the firmware. Once that process is complete and the chip reset, it reverts to its original address. At that point (after a final reboot), all is well.

I have a replacement kernel that you can install and boot which re-enables the touchpad. I'd suggest making a nandroid backup first, installing my kernel, then restoring the nandroid once it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to contact the touch controller over the I<sup>2</sup>C bus and failing. It does one retry and then gives up. The address 0x4C is correct for the mXT1386 on that unit.

- You should try a hard power off/on by taking out the battery.
- You could try taking apart the
  unit and reseating the connector to the touch controller. It is 
  on a separate board connected with a flexi cable which might have become dislodged.
- Another possibility is that the touch chip itself is damaged.